# Android show custom checkbox in custom table list view

Tags: android, checkbox

in my android app i have a custom table list view with a hidden checkbox in each row.

At the moment i have used this code in my activity to make the checkboxes visible on button press:

```
x = 1;
while (x < ListView.getChildCount()) {
    CheckBox SelectCheckBox = (CheckBox) ListView.getChildAt(x).findViewById(R.id.SelectCheckBox);
    SelectCheckBox.setChecked(false);

    SelectCheckBox = (CheckBox) ListView.getChildAt(x).findViewById(R.id.SelectCheckBox);
    SelectCheckBox.alpha = 1.0;

    x++;
}
```

Problem is, that this code shows only the checkboxes of the visible rows.
now i found here an solution to change my while ... part to:

```
for ( int x = 0; x < ListView.getAdapter().getCount(); x++) {
```

with this code i should select all rows (not only the visible rows)
but the next problem is, that my app crash at this point:

```
CheckBox SelectCheckBox = (CheckBox) ListView.getChildAt(x).findViewById(R.id.SelectCheckBox);
```

i think i have this line too.
but what i have to change?
thx :)

Log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at xxx.Overview.onOptionsItemSelected(Overview.java:309)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performOptionsItemSelected(Fragment.java:2070)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchOptionsItemSelected(FragmentManager.java:2159)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchOptionsItemSelected(FragmentController.java:295)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:367)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:147)
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:100)
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:100)
        at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$2.onMenuItemClick(ToolbarActionBar.java:68)
        at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$1.onMenuItemClick(Toolbar.java:172)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView$MenuBuilderCallback.onMenuItemSelected(ActionMenuView.java:760)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:811)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:958)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:948)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:618)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:139)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Put your complete adapter code.

Comment: Where is crash log ?

Comment: **Update Crash Log**

Comment: @Stack108 Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29440415/java-lang-nullpointerexception-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-android-view-v

Comment: my code is not in the adapter. it is in my main activity in `public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {`

Comment: I think you should call *listview.setItemChecked(position,boolean)*. Than you can get selected items with *listview.getCheckedItemPositions()*.

Comment: and how can i call with this findviewbyID?